# How to slide down div when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list where questions are shown, each question has three possible answers.

They are: `ok`, `fout` and `nvt` only with `fout` I want a div to slide down in which I can add some stuff.

Basically the answers are : good, wrong and not applicable. When an answer is wrong, I want to be able to add into an input field why it was wrong.

So beneath that answer I need a div to slidedown only when `fout` is clicked, and slide up again when one of the other two options are clicked.

How can I do this?

This is my HTML currently:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" id="questionrow">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="container text-right">
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-1" value="ok" required="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-2" value="fout">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-3" value="nvt" checked="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="container text-right">
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-4" value="ok" required="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-5" value="fout">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-6" value="nvt" checked="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="container text-right">
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-7" value="ok" required="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-8" value="fout">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-9" value="nvt" checked="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="container text-right">
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-10" value="ok" required="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-10"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-11" value="fout">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-11"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-12" value="nvt" checked="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-12"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="container text-right">
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-13" value="ok" required="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-13"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-14" value="fout">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-14"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-15" value="nvt" checked="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-15"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when for example the first question is answered with `fout`, how can I slide down a div (for example with class col-md-12) below:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="container text-right">
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-1" value="ok" required="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-2" value="fout">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-3" value="nvt" checked="">
      <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding a .slideDown() jquery function, but for this to work the HTML of the div that is supposed to slide down should already be there before the question is answered, I need the HTML to be added to the DOM when `fout` is selected.

Comment: For each question block, you have two columns: an `md-8` containing the question, and an `md-4` containing the Ok/Fout/Nvt radio buttons. Where do you want this new div created - inside the `md-8` and below the question? Or in another `md-12` div below both the `md-8 + md-4` ?

Comment: @gibberish Yes below the md-8 and md-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this. Basically,

(1) Use the HTML data attribute to store some text for each `input` radio response (you can use other methods if you wish, but this works). When the button is clicked, we grab whatever text is stored in here and save it to a variable.

(2) Then we remove any `col-md-12` divs that may have already been added (this allows you to change answers without doubling-up the response divs).

(3) Then we build the `col-md-12` that we will insert, getting the unique text from step (1) above

(4) Finally, we append the newly-constructed div to the `closest()` parent div that has a class of `.row`

**Note that I only made the first two "questions" functional, and the appearance is wonky, but this should give you an idea of how to make this work.**

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^=radio]', function(){
  var userresp = this.value;
  var ans = $(this).data('more');
  var ques = $(this).closest('.row');
  $(ques).find('.col-md-12').slideUp().remove();
  if (userresp == 'fout'){
    $('<div class="col-md-12">' +ans+ '</div>').appendTo(ques).slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
* {position: relative;box-sizing: border-box;}
body {width: 80%;}
.col-md-12{width:95%;border:1px solid green;display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-1" value="ok" data-more="Why OK is wrong" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-2" value="fout" data-more="Why fout is also wrong">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-3" value="nvt" checked="" data-more="Why nvt is correct">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-4" value="ok" required="" data-more="Second ques OK is wrong">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-5" value="fout" data-more="Second ques - fout is right-on!">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-6" value="nvt" checked="" data-more="Second question blah blah">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-7" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-8" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-9" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-10" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-10"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-11" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-11"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-12" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-12"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-13" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-13"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-14" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-14"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-15" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-15"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Example 3.

This example demonstrates how to plop different messages into the add-in DIV, based on text in the `data-more` HTML attribute on the `<input>` tag.

*This was the original answer, before I realized you specifically wanted the message DIV to appear only if the `fout` button was clicked. However, I wanted you to see the effect of using the the `data-more` attribute in a more complete example, so I reconstructed this original answer.

Comparing the two examples, you will see the difference in javascript is very, very small.*

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^=radio]', function(){
  var userresp = this.value;
  var ans = $(this).data('more');
  var ques = $(this).closest('.row');
  $(ques).find('.col-md-12').slideUp().remove();
  $('<div class="col-md-12">' +ans+ '</div>').appendTo(ques).slideDown();
});
```

```css
* {position: relative;box-sizing: border-box;}
body {width: 80%;}
.col-md-12{width:95%;border:1px solid green;display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-1" value="ok" data-more="Why OK is wrong" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-2" value="fout" data-more="Why fout is also wrong">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-3" value="nvt" checked="" data-more="Why nvt is correct">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-4" value="ok" required="" data-more="Second ques OK is wrong">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-5" value="fout" data-more="Second ques - fout is right-on!">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-6" value="nvt" checked="" data-more="Second question blah blah">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-7" value="ok" required="" data-more="DID NOT DO THESE ONES...!">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-8" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-9" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-10" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-10"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-11" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-11"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-12" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-12"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-13" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-13"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-14" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-14"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-15" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-15"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery toggle upon click of the radio box and vice versa. Use the Append function within Jquery. Then find the parent to locate the child to append and then you can add your HTML content that you wish.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: This will show/hide an already created div. I want to create a new div with jQuery (add it to the DOM).

Comment: Check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

no expert on JS, but might be an option to add the HTML to the element using jQ prior to the .slideDown() call.

Comment: I am serializing the entire form and posting it with AJAX, so hiding the divs beforehand is not really an option, a lot of empty data would be posted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Example 2: If you want the div to *slide* back up, rather than jump back up:

You can add a `callback` function (built-in) to the jQuery `.slideUp()` method. This works by waiting until the slideUp has finished before running the `.remove()` method. Previously, both were running *at the same time* so the slideUp was not noticeable.

Change this:

```
$(ques).find('.col-md-12').slideUp().remove();
```

To this:

```
$(ques).find('.col-md-12').slideUp(400, function(){
   $(ques).find('.col-md-12').remove();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^=radio]', function(){
  var userresp = this.value;
  var ans = $(this).data('more');
  var ques = $(this).closest('.row');

  /*  Adds a SlideUp if the div exists */
  $(ques).find('.col-md-12').slideUp(400, function(){
     $(ques).find('.col-md-12').remove();
  });

  if (userresp == 'fout'){
    $('<div class="col-md-12">' +ans+ '</div>').appendTo(ques).slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
* {position: relative;box-sizing: border-box;}
body {width: 80%;}
.col-md-12{width:95%;border:1px solid green;display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-1" value="ok" data-more="Why OK is wrong" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-2" value="fout" data-more="Why fout is also wrong">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?]" id="radio-3" value="nvt" checked="" data-more="Why nvt is correct">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-4" value="ok" required="" data-more="Second ques OK is wrong">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-5" value="fout" data-more="Second ques - fout is right-on!">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de specifieke VGM-regels voor het uitvoeren van de werkzaamheden (TRA)?]" id="radio-6" value="nvt" checked="" data-more="Second question blah blah">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-7" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-8" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Weten medewerkers wat zij moeten doen in geval van nood?]" id="radio-9" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-10" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-10"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-11" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-11"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?]" id="radio-12" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-12"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="questionrow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="questionvalue" class="questionclass" type="text" value="Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-13" value="ok" required="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-13"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-14" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-14"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Algemeen][Zijn de medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM-regels (VGM-instructie)?]" id="radio-15" value="nvt" checked="">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-15"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### References:

http://api.jquery.com/slideup/